# Backup VM to an existing Recovery Service Vault

Tags: json, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template, azure-backup-vault

I am able to deploy VM, but when i try to use the backup vault (which is in different resource group) i am getting the following error

***"The Resource 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/rsv-hub-centralus' under resource group 'rg-hub-centralus' was not found."***

In Json template here are the code

```
        parameters:{
        "recoveryServiceVaultName" :{
              "type" :"string",
              "metadata": {
                "description": "Existing Recovery Service Vault Name in the Subscription"
              }
            },
        }


 "variables": {
       "backupFabric": "Azure",
"backupPolicyName": "RA-standard-daily-11pm-centralus",
"v2VmType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
"v2VmContainer": "iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;",
"v2Vm": "vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;"
      },
"resources": [
    {
  "name": "[concat(parameters('recoveryServiceVaultName'), '/', variables('backupFabric'), '/', variables('v2VmContainer'), concat(resourcegroup().name,';',parameters('vmName')), '/', variables('v2Vm'), concat(resourcegroup().name,';',parameters('vmName')))]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems",
  "properties": {
    "protectedItemType": "[variables('v2VmType')]",
    "policyId": "[resourceId(parameters('vaultResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies',parameters('recoveryServiceVaultName'),variables('backupPolicyName'))]",
    "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(resourcegroup().name,'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',parameters('vmName'))]"
  }
}
  ]
```

In Powershell i am calling the json file

```
$recoveryServiceVault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "rg-hubb-recoveryservice-centralus"

$recoveryServiceVaultName = $recoveryServiceVault.Name

# Assemble template parameters
$templateParameters = @{}
$templateParameters.Add("recoveryServiceVaultName", $recoveryServiceVaultName)


New-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -Force
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile "azuredeploy.json" -TemplateParameterObject $templateParameters
```

**resourceGroup().name in "protectionContainer" and "protectionItem" - is the resourcegroup of VM or the RSV?**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's the resourgroup of the VM. Take a look at the template property about the [protectedItemId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.recoveryservices/2018-01-10/vaults/replicationfabrics/replicationprotectioncontainers/replicationprotecteditems#enableprotectioninputproperties-object). So I think the protectedItem is the VM which you want to backup. And there is also a sample template about backup, see [recovery services backup vm](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-recovery-services-backup-vms/azuredeploy.json). The variables named with the exact resource type.

Comment: i have used the same arm template which you have provided for recovery service backup vm i still have the same error. I have updated my variables and resource code

Comment: Maybe you can provide your whole template. It will be more helpful to figure out the solution.